# Get information about all CamelContext defined in a VM

Tags: apache-camel

I have a system which dynamically adds Camel contexts to a running system.

Retrieving information about the context from within a processor is very easy and convenient but I did not figure out a possibility to do so for more than the context the processor is defined in.

Is there any chance to retrieve status from all contexts using a single component?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @petter and @claus-ibsen! I've taken the MBean approach. Because I stay within my own VM, I'm able to work against the local MBeanServer:

```
    List<Map<String, String>> values = new ArrayList<>();

    QueryExp qe = Query.isInstanceOf(new StringValueExp("org.apache.camel.management.mbean.ManagedCamelContext"));
    MBeanServer ms = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
    Set<ObjectName> contexts = ms.queryNames(new ObjectName("org.apache.camel:*"), qe);

    for (ObjectName context : contexts) {

        Map<String, String> curMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

        AttributeList al = ms.getAttributes(context, attributes);
        List<Attribute> ale = al.asList();
        for (int i = 0; i < ale.size(); i++) {
            Attribute attribute = ale.get(i);

            String val = attribute.getValue() != null ? attribute.getValue().toString() : "";
            curMap.put(attribute.getName(), val);
        }

        values.add(curMap);
    }
```

With e.g. `attributes=new String[] { "CamelId", "MinProcessingTime",            "MeanProcessingTime", "MaxProcessingTime" };` I can retrieve the information I like.

Camel is great at that point ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can use JMX as Petter says. Apache Camel exposes a number of JMX MBeans to manage Camel apps: http://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/api/management/mbean/package-summary.html

I would however also point to jolokia (http://jolokia.org/) which makes using JMX much easier as jolokia can expose JMX as REST services. This makes it trivial for a client to access that information as its just a REST call (eg over HTTP).

We use this in the hawtio web console to build a HTML5 web app for managing Java apps, which has a Camel plugin as well. This allows us using those REST services to manage all the Camels running in a JVM or remote JVMs.

- http://hawt.io/

Comment: Thanks for the JMX/MBean hint!

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice piece of software that installs/uninstalls/starts/stops camel contexts on the fly that you might want to try: [Apache Karaf](http://karaf.apache.org). There are some guidelines [here](http://camel.apache.org/karaf).

That said, yes - you can easily access other Camel contexts using [JMX](http://camel.apache.org/camel-jmx.html). The contexts are exposed as MBeans. You might need to add JMX support to your dynamic runtime for this to be possible.

You can explore what options you have and if your JMX exposure works using jconsole. Of course, you can access the same operations from code using the [JMX api](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jmx/).
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the MBean hint!